# Shell Script for Delete all files in directory and print count of deleted files

Tags: linux, shell

I want to delete all files in directory and print count of deleted files using shell script.

this is my shell script to Delete All files

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /Directory/SubDirectory/*
```

I tried this

```
rm -rf /Directory/SubDirectory/*  | wc -l
```

Shell Script deleting all files but showing count as 0

My expected output as 100 files deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, by default, `rm` does not output anything, so there's nothing for `wc` to count.

You could use the `-v` option for rm (check your man page)

```
rm -vrf pattern | wc -l
# or
rm -vrf pattern | echo "$(wc -l) files deleted"
```

---

Another technique is to use `find`

```
find * -depth -print -delete | wc -l
```

Using the `-depth` directive so that a directory's files are removed before the directory itself. Demo:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
├── c
├── d
│   ├── g
│   ├── h
│   ├── i
│   └── k
│       ├── l
│       └── m
├── e
│   └── j
└── f

4 directories, 9 files

$ find * -depth -print -delete | wc -l
13

$ tree
.

0 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Thank you for your support sir.

Comment: I just want to delete files in directory. not whole directory. I found your first answer more suitable.

Comment: also is there any way to check is there any file in directory like if else condtion. I'm C# developer and new in linux.

Comment: I would expand the list of files into a shell array: `files=( "$dir"/* )` -- then you can count how many elements in the array: `if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then echo empty; fi` -- working with arrays in the shell is really ugly, and you have to be quite careful with your syntax and especially your quoting.

Answer (score 1):

flag -v, or --verbose used to explain what is being done.
The output will be like this:

```
removed 'tmp/1
removed 'tmp/2'
removed 'tmp/3'
removed directory 'tmp/'
```

By passing output through `| wc -l` you will count all of its records. 
Nuance is it will count both removed files and directories. So, if you want **only files to be counted** you should use

`rm -rfv rootDir | grep -v directory | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

rm -rfv rootDir/directory/* | wc -l

Comment: always while answering a question describe your answer in detail. It will help another user to understand your answer.